# I have a spreadsheet linked to a database in excel. How can I grab the cells from the database without the formula references changing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an external database populating a spreadsheet in my workbook. In a separate worksheet in the same workbook, I use formulas
to filter out a smaller subset of the query. The issue is any time I refresh the data, the cell references within the formulas for
 the smaller subset change. This happens any time a new element is added in the database.

I've tried using the `INDEX` and `INDIRECT` functions, but it won't allow me to use the $ symbol to prevent me from needing to individually change the formula 
50,000 times (It is a very large database).

For further clarification on the problem:

My second spreadsheet is mainly entire columns of formulas like

- `=FIRSTSPREADSHEET!$A2`
- `If (ISBLANK(DATABASE!$B2),DATABASE!$C2,DATABASE!$D2)`

Nothing
 complicated just that sort of stuff. But any time an element is added to the original database, and the data is refreshed in excel, the cell references 
are changed in the new sheet around the point where the new entries should be.

Comment: You can do a Ctrl+C, Paste Special, Values, and then you will have an immutable list of your data

Comment: The data is subject to change, wouldn't that just leave me with a one-time copy paste of the values at that current time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `INDIRECT`, however to get auto-increment, you need to use also `ROW` or `COLUMN`.

E.g. you can use this formula instead of your first example:
`=INDIRECT("FirstSpreadSheet!A"&ROW())`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing with variations of this, I'll check it out thanks.